# Android shared element fragment transitions: return transition not working

Tags: android, android-fragments, shared-element-transition

In my project I'm using a `RecyclerView` to display a list of items with thumbnails. When the user clicks on an item a DetailView gets opened, where the image is displayed on the top. I'm trying to share some elements between this fragments, but **the transition only works when entering the detail fragment, not when returning from it.**

In my `ListAdapter` I set the `TransitionName` and inform the ListFragment when the user clicks on an item:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        viewHolder.image.setTag(Constants.SHARED_NAME_IMAGE + item.itemId);
}
```

click event:

```
@OnClick(R.id.root)
 public void onClickedItem() {
        List<Pair<View, String>> sharedElements = new ArrayList<>();
        sharedElements.add(new Pair<View, String>(image, (String) image.getTag()));
        interactionListener.onItemSelected(data.get(getAdapterPosition() - headerItemCount).type, data.get(getAdapterPosition() - headerItemCount).itemId, sharedElements);
 }
```

Then in the ListFragment I'm starting the DetailFragment:

```
public void navigateToFragment(Fragment curFragment, Fragment nextFragment,
                               boolean addToBackStack, List<Pair<View, String>> sharedElements) {
    if (nextFragment == null) {
        return;
    }
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP && sharedElements != null && curFragment != null) {
        // Setup transition on first fragment
        curFragment.setSharedElementEnterTransition(TransitionUtil.getReturnTransition(this));
        curFragment.setSharedElementReturnTransition(TransitionUtil.getEnterTransition(this));
        curFragment.setEnterTransition(null);
        curFragment.setExitTransition(null);

        // Setup transition on second fragment
        nextFragment.setSharedElementEnterTransition(TransitionUtil.getEnterTransition(this));
        nextFragment.setSharedElementReturnTransition(TransitionUtil.getReturnTransition(this));
        nextFragment.setEnterTransition(null);
        nextFragment.setExitTransition(null);

        // Add second fragment by replacing first
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, nextFragment);
        if (addToBackStack) {
            ft.addToBackStack("fragment");
        }

        for (Pair<View, String> sharedElement : sharedElements) {
            ViewCompat.setTransitionName(sharedElement.first, sharedElement.second);
            ft.addSharedElement(sharedElement.first, sharedElement.second);
        }

        // Apply the transaction
        ft.commit();
    } else {
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, nextFragment);
        if (addToBackStack) {
            ft.addToBackStack("fragment");
        }
        ft.commit();
    }
}
```

Finally I'm setting the current transition name (as it depends on the itemId) in `onCreateView()` of the DetailFragment:

```
ViewCompat.setTransitionName(header, Constants.SHARED_NAME_IMAGE + itemId);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just solved the issue: there were 2 problems:

1. I've overwritten my list adapter (and therefore the transition names have been removed)
2. I haven't set the transition name in `onBindViewHolder`

To resolve #1 I changed `setUpList(){...}` like here (the first if is important!):

```
 private void setupList() {
    if (adapter != null) {
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        list.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        setScrollListener();
        return;
    }

    refreshLayout.setColorSchemeColors(ResourcesCompat.getColor(getResources(), R.color.main_color_2, getActivity().getTheme()));
    refreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            loadList(true);
        }
    });

    adapter = new ListAdapter((int) (DisplayUtils.getWidth(getActivity()) * 0.6), this);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);

    linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    list.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

    refreshLayout.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            refreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
            loadFilterItems();
```

To resolve #2 I just replaced `setTag(..)` with `setTransitionName(..)`

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                vh.image.setTransitionName(Constants.SHARED_NAME_IMAGE + item.itemId);
            }
```

and in my onClick method:

```
 List<Pair<View, String>> sharedElements = new ArrayList<>();
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            sharedElements.add(new Pair<View, String>(image, image.getTransitionName()));
        }
 interactionListener.onItemSelected(data.get(getAdapterPosition() - headerItemCount).type, data.get(getAdapterPosition() - headerItemCount).itemId, sharedElements);
```